# PrimeFaces not working with https

Tags: jsf, primefaces, https

I'm writing a CRUD web application using JSF and PrimeFaces that I want to be able to use with a secure SSL connection. I'm using GlassFish 4.0 and PrimeFaces 4.0. I'm using a self-signed SSL certificate and using 256-bit AES encryption on the GlassFish server.

My problem is that when I switch from `http:// localhost:8080/` to `https:// localhost:8181/...` Any of the PrimeFaces components that call a backing bean stop working. For instance, normally when I click on a datatable row a dialog opens. With https, it appears to hang and the dialog does not display. Similarly, when submitting a new record, the backing bean doesn't get called. I assume that the solution is something simple I haven't configured correctly. Everything works fine with ordinary http. What could be causing this?

I've included my web.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

<!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.SUBMIT</param-name>
    <param-value>partial</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/test.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer to my own question. I am using Firefox and it blocked non-encrypted parts of the website, which obviously included those parts that were not working above. Unblocking this protection returns full functionality.

I'm unsure if this means data from the database is unencrypted, so I will research this separately and post another question if necessary.